# Touch and release type of controll in Unity (Android). How to make it?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

What I would like to do, is to move the player on the screen with a single touch. So for example, if I touch the screen on the upper left corner, and my player is on the center of the screen it will turn, and move to that point where the screen was touched.

(and if it's moving and I touch the screen somewhere else, it will change directions to that point where I touched it last)

And of course, it's a topDown game.

I tried a few things but none of them worked properly and I couldn't find a good tutorial about this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script out.
1. Create a new script called **TouchMove.cs** and paste the below code
2. Assign a GameObject to the **player** Transform in the inspector
3. Set camera to orthographic, position to x & z = 0, rotate the camera 90 degrees along the x axis.
4. Hit play, and test the script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchMove : MonoBehaviour {

    //This is the player Transform. Assign it in the inspector
    public Transform player;

    //This is where we'll store the touched positon;
    public Vector3 touchPoint = Vector3.zero;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // Mouse input is registered even on mobile devices. 
        // You can always change this to use the Input.Touch class,
        // but since mouse input works on both mobile, as well as the editor
        // I use Input.GetMouse instead.
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

            //We take the point where the touch occured and convert the units
            //of this touch from screen space to world space
            //Unity's API doc for ScreenToWorldPoint
            //http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html
            touchPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            Debug.Log (touchPoint);

            //I assume that the camera is looking "down" on the player.
            //Therefor the player moves only on the X & Z axis. We want to keep the player's
            //Y co-ordinate the same so that it doesn't move further away or closer to the camera
            //If your camera is oriented differently (i.e. other than in the Y axis, looking down)
            //change the below line.
            touchPoint.y = player.position.y;

        }

        //The player is not at the touched position, so we need to rotate
        //the player to look at the final touch position, and move the player toward that position
        if(!Mathf.Approximately(player.position.x, touchPoint.x) ||
           !Mathf.Approximately(player.position.z, touchPoint.z) ) {

            player.LookAt(touchPoint);

            player.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but my sprite doesn't rotate to the point where the screen was touched and it's becomes invisible sometimes. (when it reaches the point where the screen was touched. And in the beginning it's invisible)

Comment: Ahh, when I wrote the code I assumed you were using a 3D object, not a sprite. Your sprite is not becoming invisible, rather it gets rotated due to this line of code player.LookAt(touchPoint); I assume you should be able to fix this?

Comment: I tried to change the z parameters to y but it's still "invisible"